# Paste together results within case_when (if-else) statements

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I want to paste together results within the same `case_when` statement (i.e., if multiple statements are true for a given row). I know that I could do something like below to create additional columns and then `unite` them together. But what is the best way to make the code more efficient (and less verbose) without having to explicitly create `var.m` and `var.o`?

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(
  ind = 1:10,
  var = c(-21, -60, 7, 8,
           9, 10, NA, 14, 101, 160)
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(
    var.m = ifelse(row.names(df) %in% (which(abs(diff(var, lag = 1)) > 10)), "derivative", NA),
    var.o = ifelse((var + 50) > 90, "add", NA),
    results = case_when(is.na(var) ~ "Missing Data",
                     var > 100 ~ "High",
                     var < -20 ~ "Low")) %>%
  unite(
    "message",
    c(var.m, results, var.o),
    sep = "_",
    remove = TRUE,
    na.rm = TRUE
  )
```

**Output/Expected Output**

```
   ind var             message
1    1 -21      derivative_Low
2    2 -60      derivative_Low
3    3   7                    
4    4   8                    
5    5   9                    
6    6  10                    
7    7  NA        Missing Data
8    8  14          derivative
9    9 101 derivative_High_add
10  10 160            High_add
```

So, in other words, is it possible to forgo creating `var.m` and `var.o` and do everything within `case_when`? Or is there an alternative to creating multiple variables (i.e., `var.m` and `var.o`) before concatenating the messages together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    message = paste(
      coalesce(if_else(c(abs(diff(var, lag = 1)) > 10, FALSE), "derivative", ""), ""),
      coalesce(if_else((var+50) > 90, "add", ""), ""),
      coalesce(case_when(
        is.na(var) ~ "Missing Data",
        var > 100 ~ "High",
        var < -20 ~ "Low"), ""),
      sep = "_"),
    message = gsub("^_|_$", "",
                   gsub("__", "_", message))
  )
#    ind var             message
# 1    1 -21      derivative_Low
# 2    2 -60      derivative_Low
# 3    3   7                    
# 4    4   8                    
# 5    5   9                    
# 6    6  10                    
# 7    7  NA        Missing Data
# 8    8  14          derivative
# 9    9 101 derivative_add_High
# 10  10 160            add_High
```

The `coalesce` calls are because any one of them could be `NA` because of the possibility of things slipping through. I could add `!is.na(var)` before some of the conditionals, but `diff` introduces a challenge since we'd also need `!lead(is.na(var),default=F)` or such; and for that `coalesce` just seemed simpler.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was looking for something slightly different. I updated the question, as I should have been a little more explicit in what I was looking for. Essentially, I'm wondering if it is possible to forgo having to create `var.m` or `var.o` and do everything within the same step as `case_when` or something similar. But maybe that's not possible.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry for misunderstanding. Edit coming ...

Comment: So, it is possible, but kind of takes it out of the normal `tidyr` format. But interestingly, the updated answer is faster than your first answer and my answer (in the question) (at least according to the `microbenchmark` I ran).

Comment: Yes, I don't know of any easy, logical, uncomplicated way to combine all three completely-disparate things into one elegant flow. Sorry to disappoint, perhaps somebody else will think of something.